# Joomla Wrong Time Zone on insert / update DB

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am developing a plugin and at some point I submit a time value to mariadbb 10.1 in a time field. Maria DB timezone is set to 'Europe/Athens' both for the global and the session time_zone varialbe.

Although in my global configuration I have set the website Time Zone to "Europe/Athens" my value is inserted as UTC time, 3 hours earlier.

The output of the date_default_timezone_get() is 'UTC' so the above faulty behavior is expected.
I have not change somewhere else the timezone so I am stuck.

I don't want to execute date_default_timezone_set() everywhere. I would prefer to use Joomla global set variable.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem that 's how I solved it.

I was filling values with date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). By changing to

```
$d = new DateTime('now', $timeZone)
```

solved my problem. Where $timeZone is a DateTimeZone. Thus my dates had datetime zone information.

Another point was at calendar fields where I had to set filter="none" instead of the "utc" which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem already, let set timezone of server with same timezone of Joomla then everything is will be fine.